# Checking static or dynamic IP address in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a pretty basic form app.

I can get a list of IP addresses available on the local machine. However, I want to also determine how these addresses are obtained (e.g. DHCP or static). How can I tell if a static IP address is configured on the system?

The goal is to inform a novice end-user (who may have no knowledge of the network setup, or how to obtain it) what static IP addresses are available. And, if no static address exist, inform them that one needs to be setup.

TIA

Comment: If they have no knowledge of the network setup or how to determine it, how are they going to make a static IP address when you tell them they need one?

Comment: Also consider that they may have configured their DHCP server to consistently give them the same address.  Hence it may be dynamically allocated yet always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll probably have to use WMI.  There might be another way, but this is the only way that I know.

This code will output all of the information about every adapter on your system.  I think the name is "DHCPEnabled" of the property you want.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherNetwork =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
"SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcherNetwork.Get())
{
     foreach (var prop in queryObj.Properties)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} Value: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value));
     }
}
```

Comment: This required a little work, but was basically what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @robotshapes Required a little work you say. Does this mean your resulting code is much different to the code above? If so, please share it.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins: It actually looks like there are new APIs for this as pointed out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21773912/3244. That looks way better. The "accepted" answer doesn't reflect the passage of time, unfortunately. It's a little quirk with Stackoverflow. Make sure you look at the upvotes on the other answers when you evaluate a solution.

Answer (score 17):

Better use Net.NetworkInformation due to better performance compared to WMI

```
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    NetworkInterface[] niAdpaters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    private Boolean GetDhcp(Int32 iSelectedAdpater)
    {
        if (niAdpaters[iSelectedAdpater].GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties() != null)
        {
            return niAdpaters[iSelectedAdpater].GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use WMI to get network adapter configuration.

For an example, have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx.  The 'DhcpEnabled' property on the network adapter should tell you if the address is obtained via dhcp or not.

Answer (score 1):

I use two method(s) as follows:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();

        }

    }

    return "unknown";
}

public static string GetLocalIpAllocationMode()
{
    string MethodResult = "";
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcherNetwork = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

        Dictionary<string, string> Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcherNetwork.Get())
        {
            foreach (var prop in queryObj.Properties)
            {
                if (prop.Name != null && prop.Value != null && !Properties.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    Properties.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString());

                }

            }

        }

        MethodResult = Properties["DHCPEnabled"].ToLower() == "true" ? "DHCP" : "Static";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.HandleException();

    }

    return MethodResult;

}
```

`GetLocalIpAllocationMode()` will tell you whether the `ip` is `static` or allocated via `dhcp`, whereas `GetLocalIPAddress()` will tell you the local `ip` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here helped me with my own project, but I had to do some research before I found out how to use the suggested method.

Adding using `System.Management;` to your code doesn't work by itself. You need to add a reference to System.Management before the namespace will be recognized. (For new people like me who tried this and were getting the error "managementclass could not be found").