# How can I know if I'm using Fixed IP or DHCP in windows mobile using C#

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

I am building a project and I need to know if a `HandHeld` using windows mobile 6.5 is using Fixed IP or DHCP using `C#`.

I can't find anything about that `:/`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [IsDhcpEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfaceproperties.isdhcpenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part of the System.Net.NetworkInformation Namespace if you're using .Net framework 3.0+. You may also look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890449/checking-static-or-dynamic-ip-address-in-c-sharp-net) it seems this user is also attempting to something similiar.

Comment: In windows mobile it doesn't exists "System.Net.NetworkInformation". I've tried with that already.