# How to detect static or dynamic IP address in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have got following code from [Checking static or dynamic IP address in C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890449/checking-static-or-dynamic-ip-address-in-c-sharp-net)

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Private niAdpaters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

Private Function GetDhcp(iSelectedAdpater As Int32) As [Boolean]
    If niAdpaters(iSelectedAdpater).GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties() IsNot Nothing Then
        Return niAdpaters(iSelectedAdpater).GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

But I dont understand how to use above code.

Comment: What if you have both? You can have more than one network connection that might not be configured the same. For example, say you have a network port that statically assigned and wifi card that gets a dynamic address. My laptop is actually setup that way right now, because I need a static address on the LAN port for managing some of my server and switch equipment. How do you want to handle that kind of situation?

Comment: It depends. You may have a number of separate cabled connections. For example, I have a server with four network ports. The main interface is a static IP, but on the others is set for a different vlan and uses a dynamic address.

Comment: The IP of the network interface on your computer where the C# code runs is different than the IP provided by your ISP. There is a NAT layer in between provided by your modem/router segmenting your home into a completely separate and private network, meaning what you're looking at won't tell you at all what you want to know. Inside that network, it's probably gonna show "dynamic" no matter what you do with your C# code, even if your ISP is correctly providing the static address.

Comment: It won't help. You need to look at the addressing of your modem/router, not at what your computer is doing. Even then, your ISP may have set the modem to use DHCP, and is enforcing the static address via a dhcp reservation. The **ONLY** way to see this for sure is to see your ISP's routing tables, or to just watch it over time and note that it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `GetDhcp` expects the selected adapter as its argument, so you nee to call it like this:

```
If GetDhcp(1) = True Then
   ...
```

or simply

```
If GetDhcp(1) Then
    ...
```

where `1` represents the index of the adapter in the list of all NetworkInterfaces.

You will have to inspect the list to find the desired NetworkInterface to check as Joel pointed out.

You can have an arbitrary number of adapters on your system like wifi, LAN or even virtual adapters (virtual machines running on your host OS).

Comment: Check [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx) and [NetworkInterface Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) - this is related to your OS settings, not to your ISP - unless you are running your code on a machine with a direct WAN connection.